# Can I use Entity Framework to track changes like DataSet (without connecting to database)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use DataSet to write to the database in my desktop WPF application.

I create one DataSet for one Survey Window that contains several different documents.
I add some starting data (add new rows to several tables) then I bind it to the appropriate fields (TextBoxes, CheckBoxes).

Now DataSet has changes, but I can reset them:

```cs
dataSet.AcceptChanges();
```

Than, when a user change something, I can track the changes using:

```cs
dataSet.HasChanges();
dataSet.GetChanges();
```

I would like to transfer the application to Entity Framework.

I found that I could bind to `dbContext.MyTable.Local`, and check changes by `dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()`. However, I can't find a way to add some data and reset HasChanges() status.

Is this possible to using model and classes generated by EF without open connection to database?

Should I build my own model and use EF only for writing to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your entities to the context using the `Attach` method:

```
dbContext.MyTable.Attach(myRow);
```

This will add the entity with an EntityState of Unchanged:

```
dbContext.Entry(myRow).State == EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Once you apply changes to your entity, the entity tracker will detect these changes:

```
dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()
```

However, since your entities are not really coming from the database you may need to change the entity state to Added if you want to insert these records, and then `dbContext.SaveChanges()` will handle the rest.

```
if(dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
{
    dbContext.Entry(myRow).State = EntityState.Added;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

For more info see [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state).

HTH

Comment: "you may need to change the entity state to Added" that's exactly what I'm doing with dataset :). Thank you for your answer.
Do you know how to programmatically set connection parameters and remove entity framework configuration from App.config?

Comment: @marbel82 Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350851/entity-framework-6-set-connection-string-in-code